# Использование size_t

Tags: c++

Добрый день. Помогите определиться когда оправдано применение типа size_t? Заглянул в [Google C++ Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml), в разделе integer types. Там написано что sizet используйте когда это необходимо. Мне казалось он хорошо подходит на роль счётчиков циклов, но в том же стандарте сказано что они обычно для этого используют int. В общем хотелось бы узнать про случаи когда всё таки без sizet не обойтись. Спасибо.

Comment: Когда надо работать с длинной массива, который предполагает содержание большого количества элементов. Для итерации по введенной пользователем строке будет достаточно простого инта, для чтения из файла лучше использовать `size_t`. Кроме того, это прекрасный способ "маякнуть" другим разработчиком о том, что находится в переменной или возвращается функцией.

Comment: @mks, делайте, как удобней.

Я, вот, достаточно ленив и поэтому обычно почти везде тоже пишу *int*, хотя в душе согласен, что почти всегда правильней было бы написать `size_t`   (или `ssize_t` или явно указать желаемый размер и знак (uint32_t и т.п.)).

Comment: Всё просто. Лично я стараюсь использовать `size_t` везде, где речь идёт о размере. И всегда, без "стараюсь" - там, где присутствует `sizeof` или хотя бы одна функция/метод, возвращающий/принимающий `size_t`. Ну, то есть голову не ломаю над такими вопросами вообще: где надо, и где это логично, там и использую.

Comment: @mks, а с другими рекомендациями, вроде используйте `printf/scanf` вместо `<<` и '>>` (streams) Вы согласны?

Comment: @avp знаете с printf и >> как то не возникает чувства внутренего противоречия :)

Comment: @mks, а знаете, я тут повспоминал процесс написаписания разных программы, подумал, и мне теперь кажется, что в google, рекомендуя обычно использовать *int* правы.

Как-то с ним ошибки выявляются легче (чем с `unsigned`, а ведь `size_t` это беззнаковый тип). Да и некоторые алгоритмы, похоже, программируются проще с *int*, используя отрицательные величины, как особые случаи. И т.п.

--

Но особо в их рекомендациях порадовало -- *не используйте исключения* 

(видимо они накопили большой отрицательный опыт с программистами, которые любят try ...).

Answer (score 5):

Вот здесь хорошо описано

http://www.viva64.com/ru/a/0050/#ID0EWEAC

```
Тип size_t обычно применяется для счетчиков циклов, индексации массивов, хранения размеров, адресной арифметики
```

Для счётчиков циклов, видимо имеется ввиду цикл прохода по массиву.

Comment: Да эту статью я читал. Собственно я до прочтения гугловского стандарта обычно и использовал size_t для счётчиков циклов, индексов масивов и т.д. Но вот вопрос почему в гугле считают по другому. Единственный аргумент у них это пример с бесконечным циклом. Получается они это делают для дополнительной страховки от ошибок?

Comment: Они пишут "в подходящих случаях используйте size_t". Адресация - это подходящий случай, size_t был создан именно для этого.

Пример с циклом спорный, если Lenght() возвращает int, а не uint, то получается что 1) контейнер может иметь только 1/2 от максимально возможного размера 2) теоретически возможно использование отрицательных индексов.

А вот на цикл *(int i = Lenght();...)* при Lenght() возвращающем uint, должен ругнуться даже студенческий компилятор, выполненный в рамках курсовой работы.

Answer (score 2):

size_t - псевдоним (alias), зависит от реализации (ulong uint что-нибудь еще). Улучшает портируемость.
Где использовать желательно:

При написании своих шаблонов. 
В работе со стандартными контейнерами как тип размера или количества. (все контейнеры поддерживают).